# How to spread/optimize this javascript code

Tags: javascript

I have this function:

```
function(x, callBack) {
         const c = x?.properties.color || red
         const h = x?.properties.high || 1
         const a = x?.properties.alt || 5
         const la = x?.properties.lat || 4
         const lo = x?.properties.lon || 3
         const w = x?.properties.width ||| 2
         callBack(c, h, a, la, lo, w)
}
```

How can I reduce the number of lines using this operator `{ color } = x?.properties` ?. My problem is the default values.

Answer (score 3):

Since all the values are inside `properties`, we can use the spread syntax with the fallback values.

The only 'change' happening is that instead of the short variable names, you'll need to use the original keys

```js
function fooBar(x, callBack) {
    const {
      color = 'red',
      high = 1,
      alt = 5
    } = x?.properties || {};
    
    callBack(color, high, alt);
}

fooBar({ properties: { color: 'orange' } }, (...all) => console.log('#1', all));
fooBar({ properties: undefined }, (...all) => console.log('#2', all));
```

---

**Note**: As [@Felix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72274007/how-to-spread-optimize-this-javascript-code/72274090#comment127687202_72274090) mentioned, keep in mind that the [logical OR (`||`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR) has some other behaviour than the fallback `=`.

Comment: Just pointing out that using a default value and doing `... || ...` won't always produce the same result (although the default value is what the OP should probably use).

Comment: `x?.properties` this can be undefined also, In that case, it'll throw an error.

Comment: @RahulSharma That's no different from OP's example.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle it like this, but when you check of nullish operator it might return undefined, you have to take care of that in advance.

```
  function (x, callBack) {
      const properties =  x?.properties || {};
      const {
        color = 'red',
        high = 1,
        alt = 5,
        lat = 4,
        lon = 3,
        width = 2
      } = properties;
      callBack(color, high, alt, lat, lon, width);
    }
```

Comment: Just pointing out that using a default value and doing `... || ...` won't always produce the same result  (although the default value is what the OP should probably use).

Answer (score 1):

You can go all the way using [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring):

```js
function f({properties: {color: c = 'red', high: h = 1, alt: a = 5, lat: la = 4, lon: lo = 3, width: w = 2} = {}} = {}, callBack) {
  callBack(c, h, a, la, lo, w);
}

const callbackFunction = function() {
  console.log(...arguments);
}

f(undefined, callbackFunction)
f({ properties: {} }, callbackFunction)
f({ properties: { color: 'test', alt: 4 } }, callbackFunction)
```

Or, if you don't need to rename all the variables, simply use

```js
function f({properties: {color = 'red', high = 1, alt = 5, lat = 4, lon = 3, width = 2} = {}} = {}, callBack) {
  callBack(color, high, alt, lat, lon, width);
}
```

I've used `= {}` twice (once to set the default value of the `properties` property to an empty object in case it is absent and once to set the default value of the first parameter as a whole to an empty object in case it is completely absent/`undefined`) so that it wont throw any errors in those cases. This is slightly different from your code, where it *will* throw an error if an object is passed, but the `properties` property is missing.

Another small difference is that `||` will use the right-hand operand for any [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value, whereas the default value in object destructuring is only used when its value is `undefined`.

Comment: Could you explain the `} = {}} = {}` bit, pls?